# how to use maxAggregation in jest elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

i want to get the maximun id form a subfield of an aptitude object,

```
{
"mappings": {
    "aptitude": {
        "dynamic": "strict",
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "es": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "en": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "behaviors": {
                "properties": {
                    "id": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "es": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "en": {
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see the aptitude have an array of behaviors who in turn have an id, afaik i should use the maxAggregation from Jest, but cant find a decent example of how to do it in java, can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the way like this:

```
String query = "{\n"
            +"    \"query\" : {\n"
            +"        \"match\" : {\"id\":" + aptitudeId + "}\n"
            +"    },\n"
            +"    \"aggs\" : {\n"
            +"        \"max1\" : {\n"
            +"            \"max\" : {\n"
            +"                \"field\" : \"behaviors.id\"\n"
            +"            }\n"
            +"        }\n"
            +"    }\n"
            +"}";
```

i was looking into the aggregation builders from jest but doing it via query was much easier.

the return looks like this:

```
Search search = new Search.Builder(query)
            .addIndex(aptitudeIndexName)
            .addType(aptitudeTypeName)
            .build();

    try {
        SearchResult result = client.execute(search);


        MaxAggregation max1 = result.getAggregations().getMaxAggregation("max1");
        Double max = max1.getMax();
        return max.longValue() + 1;//so it would add 1 to the current maximum id
```